# How to get this shape as border on a menu item?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm creating a menu, and I want to achieve this look when you hover a menu item:

[image]

As you can see, when you hover a menu item (a hovered `li a`) this light blue shape appears.

Is there a way to achieve this using Pseudo elements like `li a:hover:after` or `border-bottom` without having to use tricky "hidden image" techniques?

Comment: Use a background image on the hover pseudo element.  It's not 'tricky'.

Comment: you could probably create something like it without images, but it might not have that glowy look or be 100% perfect.  I think your best bet is to just use an image as a background on the hover state.  And like @Brian said, there's nothing tricky about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `:after` pseudo-element for border and `border-radius` to create that shape of border.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 130%;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-15%);
  background: #5F8AAA;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use `radial-gradient` where you can get more control over how the border will look like.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 130%;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-15%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(111,182,232,1) 0%, rgba(111,182,232,1) 40%, rgba(211,229,242,1) 70%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
li:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hmm. That's awesome

Comment: Good job. I was typing out a solution similar to this but yours is perfect.

Comment: I think you meant `radial-gradient` :) (Btw, the `radial-gradient` approach should be possible without the need for a pseudo also. Can't do a demo now.)

Comment: Yep that is exactly what i meant, thanks :). Note that border has larger width then text but must also by dynamic to width of text, i mean that is what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the image as a background of the `li`, you just need to find the right position.

```
ul li ul li:hover {background-image: url("images/yourShapeImage.png");}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.divclass

    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
.topmenu a:hover{
    border-bottom-color: blue;
}
```

its not as fancy, but its a start

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anqweymd/

Comment: The idea is to achieve the border shape somehow :) Thanks!